# Как сделать редирект на раздел uri верхнего уровня?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, редирект

Есть сайт. На сайте есть каталог Doclist. Что нужно прописать в .htacсess,  чтобы запросы вида:
site.ru/Doclist/dsaafs/dsad.htm
site.ru/Doclist/asdsadas/
site.ru/Doclist/dsadsa/sadasd/sdasad/5.htm
перенаправлялись по адресу site.ru/Doclist ?

Comment: А для чего, если не секрет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^Doclist/([^/]+/)+([^/]+\.htm)?$ /Doclist/ [R=301,L]
```

Сработает для всех подразделов и файлов с расширением .htm. Для подразделов слэш в конце обязателен.